# Working with staging and Live url wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I made my wordpress site live by moving it from the staging url (staging.example.com) to the live url(www.example.com).
I wont be working on the site anymore so I have to advice my client on how to manage things on his own from now on.

I have 2 options:

1. Let the client add blog posts directly on the live. When it comes to installing plugins or 
   any other changes that might cause the site to break, I can ask him to clone the live site by
   using plugins such as wp-staging, test the changes on staging url and if everything works as
   expected, then make the same changes in live.
2. I can ask him to make ***all*** the changes (adding posts, plugins etc.) on the staging url first and then transfer the 
   files to the live url. But how would we transfer the db from stage to live without overwriting the live db?
   Also I used this [script](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) 
   to change the url in db but I dont want to let my client use that script because being a non-technical person,
   I am afraid that he might end up deleting the entire files on the server or that he might forget to
   delete the script after using it.

Or is there a better option? I am new to wordpress. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a backup plugin like backupwordpress or any of the other popular options out there to backup the database and files on a regular basis. Then run the backup right before making any plugin/theme updates.

Comment: Thanks. So you are saying that the stage url is not needed anymore and that all the changes can be made on the live directly after taking a backup? But if something goes wrong, the live site would remain broken until the backup is restored right?

Comment: Yes exactly. But it would save him from making changes on the staging environment and then syncing to the live site. Generally, for really large changes I would go with a staging environment but general maintenance stuff I use the backups on the live environment. Many WP plugins warn you if they have made large changes (at least really popular plugins do).

Answer (score 0):

Well usually staging urls are used when developing plugins or themes. In your case you are simply installing new plugins and adding posts to the WordPress. This is how WordPress is normally used and it does not require a development site.

If your client installs well known WordPress plugins which are well tested, then he should not have any problems with installing them.